# Need assistance for loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to output each number 1-50. Before hand I am prompting the user for their favorite number, and when I get to that number, I want to exclude it from the list, and basically console.log or alert() the user that I don't like that number, then continue on with listing the rest. Here is what I have but It's not working how I intended. Mind you we just started learning about loops today. And if you can explain what things are doing in your answer, so I can fully comprehend, it would be a great help! Thank you!

```js
var prmpt = prompt("Enter your fav number, 1-50");

for (i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
  console.log(i);
  if (i === prmpt) {
    console.log("Yikes, get this " + prmpt + " number outta here!");
  }
  continue;
}
```

Comment: What does not work? What does console.log(i) print? P.S. I don't think you need that "continue".

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing a string (`prmpt`) with the numbers. Parse that as an integer with [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) and then your comparisons will work as intended:

```
var prmpt = parseInt(prompt("Enter your fav number, 1-50"));
```

You also don't need a `continue` because the loop will automatically keep executing till `i` is `50` (but make sure you log either `i` or `Yikes...` and not both):

```js
var prmpt = parseInt(prompt("Enter your fav number, 1-50"));
for (i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
  if (i === prmpt) {
    console.log("Yikes, get this " + prmpt + " number outta here!");
  } else {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple task buddy. All you need to do is:

1. In the `if` loop while checking if `i` is equal to the `prmpt` value, convert the `prmpt` to `int` using `parseInt(prmpt)`, because the `prmpt` value is a string. Hence "1" which is a `string` is not equal to `1` which is an `int`.
2. use the `continue` inside the `if` loop that checks if `i ===
   prmpt`. This is done because, `continue` is used to skip that particular iteration, and in case of your problem it needs to be skipped only if its equal to `prmpt`. Hence use the `continue` inside the `if`.
3. The printing `i` value part should be done after the `if` loop. If the `console.log` is given before the `if`, then it will print the `i` value even before it checks if it is equal to the `prmpt` value.

Run the script below and check if this is what you need.

```js
var prmpt = prompt("Enter your fav number, 1-50");

for (i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {

  if (i === parseInt(prmpt)) {
    console.log("Yikes, get this " + prmpt + " number outta here!");
    continue;
  }
  console.log(i);
}
```